# Reactjs: How to access ref of child component in parent component as well as in child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React.js I am using ref in parent component to get the child element.

**PARENT COMPONENT**

```
constructor(){
    this.setModalRef = element => {
        this.accountModal = element;
    };
}


render() {
    return(
        <ChildComponent modalRef={this.setModalRef} />
    )
}
```

**CHILD COMPONENT

```
render() {
    return(
        <Modal ref={this.props.modalRef}> </Modal>
    )
}
```

I am able to access ref in parent component using **this.accountModal**. Here I want to access the ref in child component as well. I am not able to access the ref in child element. Please let me there is any way to access child component element in parent as well as in child component. Thank you.

Comment: You have passed `modalRef` as a prop to `ChildComponent` so to access the ref, you just need to do: `this.props.modalRef` and this is what you are doing already in order to pass it to `Modal` component

Comment: @Yousaf this.props.modalRef returns me the function of setModalRef in child component

Comment: use it like this: `<ChildComponent modalRef={this.setModalRef} modal={this.accountModal />` And access it with `this.props.modal` in the child component

Comment: That's because it is a function. See [React - Creating Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs)

Comment: @TasosBu I tried this.props.modal in child component gives undefined